# Update Org Header if SRC Block has :tangle no

Tags: org-mode, todo

I organize my `init.el` in a single org-file as many do. Often times I remove code from my config to test things out. I typically do this by changing the src-block to have a `:tangle no` setting. In many cases, I forget about it and eventually realize large portions of my config are not tangled.

I'm not quite sure if I need to craft some type of watcher or hook function.

```
* This is a heading

    #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
    ...
    #+END_SRC

would become

* TODO This is a heading

    #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle no
    ...
    #+END_SRC
```

I was thinking about adding something like this to an on-save hook and then modifying the code blocks section header if :tangle no.

```
(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'src-block #'identity nil nil 'src-block)
```

But it takes a really long time just to run this function.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. E.g. why isn't a global search-and-replace of `:tangle no` to nothing  enough?

Comment: @NickD Good point, another added benefit would be when knitting my init.el  file to html, non-tangled blocks can be differentiated from tangled blocks.

Answer (score 1):

On my computer, sections with todo keyword `COMMENT` are not tangled. That is, change your `TODO` example to `* COMMENT This is a heading`. It is also fairly easy to toggle the `COMMENT` keyword, with `C-;` keystroke anywhere on or within a heading.